# Querying by field in MongoDB, which can be arbitrarily deeply nested in the document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am currently developing a RESTful API/thinking about the implementation.
For the sake of simplicity, in my model, there's a document type, called 'Box'. A box can contain items, and other boxes as well. (Kind of like a composite pattern) Such sub-boxes can be arbitrarily deeply nested.

In MongoDB, such a box document would look like this:

```
{
    _id: 0,
    items: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    sub-boxes: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            items: ['D', 'E']
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            items: []
            sub-boxes: [
                {
                    _id: 3,
                    items: ['G']
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My REST API url looks like this:
GET /api/boxes/:id

I would like to be able to retrieve the box #0 the same way as #3 (from an API point of view).
GET /api/boxes/0
GET /api/boxes/3

My question is that is it possible in MongoDB to query for the field _id, even if I don't know how deeply it is nested in the document? I cannot hardcode in my queries the location of _id, since it can be basically anywhere.

I know that I could normalize my model, so each 'sub-boxes' property would only contain references to other boxes, but I would prefer to keep my model denormalized, if possible.

Comment: No this is not possible. Denormalization is the only solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to normalize my data, so each box only contains references to other boxes.